# Syntax error when specifying Java Xbootclasspath argument

Tags: java, command-line, windows-7, classpath, executable-jar

Please note: Why I want to use `-Xbootclasspath` is outside the scope of this question and requires an imppossibly-long backstory not worthy of StackOverflow. Just know: I *need* to use it.

On Windows 7 here. My directory structure is like so:

```
C:/Users/myuser/myapp/
    myapp.jar
    lib/
        abc.jar
        def.jar
        ghi.jar
```

Where `myapp.jar` is the executable JAR (the app), and everything in `lib` is just a 3rd party dependency.

I'm looking for the correct command line invocation for running `myapp.jar` with its classpath set up to such that everything under `lib` is on the `-Xbootclasspath`. The best I could find was:

```
java -Xbootclasspath:lib/abc.jar;lib/def.jar;lib/ghi.jar -jar myapp.jar
```

But when I run this from the `myapp/` directory I get:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
-bash: lib/abc.jar: cannot execute binary file
-bash: lib/def.jar: cannot execute binary file
-bash: lib/ghi.jar: cannot execute binary file
```

(I'm using Cygwin here.)

Any ideas as to what I need to change to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing colon after -Xbootclasspath:

java -Xbootclasspath/a:lib/abc.jar;lib/def.jar;lib/ghi.jar -jar myapp.jar

Comment: Thanks @almas shaikh (+1) - I tried your recommended changes but this still gives me errors, please see my update which contains the latest error message. Thanks again!

Comment: Append your libs to existing bootup classes. See i edited the answer.